# How do I save and load the current time in java?

Tags: java, time, load, save

I need to be able to save and load the current time in java. I could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to store it in a long, but I also need to be able to write it out in different formats, like; "yyyy-mm-dd", "dd/mm hour:min:sec", and such.

The program will save the time I got from `System.currentTimeMillis()` into a txt file, so even if something happens to the computer or program it needs to be able to just go right back to it's task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code similar to the following

```
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

### Serializing

Serializing to text:

```
java.time.Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-01-01T01:23:45.123456789Z

Instantiate from text:

```
Instant.parse( “2018-01-01T01:23:45.123456789Z” )
```

### Formatted strings

Adjust into time zone:

```
instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) )  // Instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` object
```

Generate strings in other formats:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( … )
```

…or, better:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…
```

…then:

```
myZonedDateTime.format( formatter )
```

## Track Date-Time Values, Not Milliseconds

Generally speaking, tracking date-time values by millisecond-since-epoch is tricky business and should be avoided. The values are meaningless when read by humans. Different software uses different numbers (seconds versus milliseconds versus nanoseconds). Different software uses different [epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (not always the beginning of 1970 as you may be expecting). Tracking by date-time values by milliseconds like trying to track text by bits rather than using *String*, *FileReader*, and *FileWriter* objects. We have good date-time libraries, so use them.

## Joda-Time | java.time

By good date-time libraries, I am referring to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8. Avoid the older bundled classes, java.util.Date & .Calendar, as they are notoriously troublesome.

To get started with Joda-Time, try:

```
System.out.println( DateTime.now() );
```

Then search StackOverflow for "joda" or "joda date".

## ISO 8601

When serializing date-time values to text storage, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of `YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS.sss+00:00` such as `2014-03-11T23:54:15+01:00` or `2014-03-11T22:54:15Z`. This format is unambiguous. The format is intuitive across various cultures. The values when sorted alphabetically are also sorted chronologically.

The Joda-Time library uses the ISO 8601 format by default. Similarly the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310) also uses ISO 8601 but extends that format by appending in brackets the proper name of the time zone such as `2014-03-11T15:54:15+08:00[America/Los_Angeles]`.

Comment: I'm going to take that into consideration, the biggest concern I have is that it's much easier to calculate the time between two dates when it is in milliseconds.

Comment: @Yemto Date-time work is a tricky slippery challenge. Working with milliseconds may *seem* easier, but in the long run it is not.  To determine a span of time between two date-times, use the `Interval` class in Joda-Time (and similar in java.time in Java 8). Search StackOverflow for "joda interval" to find examples. Along with `Interval`, look at `Period` and `Duration` for handling various aspects of a span of time.

Answer (score 1):

store as long value returned from `System.currentTimeMillis()` and load back using `Date date=new Date(long value);`

You can use Calendar class or SimpleDateFormat as shown in below code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Read more about [Date formatting using SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Date 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html
And for formatting you need SimpleDateFormat

```
Date date = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

You can either use a text file or you could use the ObjectOutputStream because Date is Serializable.